# Stumped with Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[image]

(a) How do we find $A^{-1}$?

(b) If $XA=B$, how do we use (a) to find $X$?

Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: To answer (b), $X=BA^{-1}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(a) Note that for any invertible $2\times 2$ matrix $A$:

$$\mathbf{A}^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \\ \end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \frac{1}{\det(\mathbf{A})} \begin{bmatrix} \,\,\,d & \!\!-b \\ -c & \,a \\ \end{bmatrix} = \frac{1}{ad - bc} \begin{bmatrix} \,\,\,d & \!\!-b \\ -c & \,a \\ \end{bmatrix}. $$

(b) Again, since $A^{-1}$ exists, $$XA = B \iff XAA^{-1} = X =  BA^{-1}$$

Comment: I love the $()$ version for matrices. +)

Comment: @amWhy: Agree with B, +1

Answer (score 2):

For 2x2 matrices there is a shortcut:  use the matrix

```
-2 7
-1 3
```

(sorry haven't learned MathJax yet).

and multiply it by 1/detA

In the 2x2 case det A is ad - bc where a and d are the diagonal terms and b,d the off diagonal terms; so you get detA -6 - (-7) = 1.

Of course you can brute force it:  multiply A by

```
a b
c d
```

and set it equal to

```
1 0
0 1
```

you will then have 4 equations in the unknowns a,b,c,d but they are very easy to solve.